# How to send array of json to mvc controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I want to send an array of json to my controller but in controller I can not get it, can anyone help me?

this is my js code:

```
function fn_SaveData() {
    debugger;
    var jsonArray = [];
    $.each($("form input:not([type='button'])"), function () {
        debugger;
        var _id = $(this).attr("id");
        jsonArray.push({ "pData": { Id: _id, Value: $(this).val() } });
    });
    var pData = JSON.stringify(jsonArray);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/BPMS/FormHome/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        data: pData,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

and here is my classes:

```
public class FormFieldsArrayDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootFormFieldsArray
{
    public FormFieldsArrayDto pData { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetData(List<RootFormFieldsArray> pData)
    {
        return Json(new { x = "1"});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `_id` and `$(this).val()`  contain value as expected Now Change your code like the following:-

```
function fn_SaveData() {
    debugger;
    var jsonArray = [];
    $.each($("form input:not([type='button'])"), function () {
        debugger;
        var _id = $(this).attr("id");
        jsonArray.push({ "pData": { Id: _id, Value: $(this).val() } });
    });
     
    $.ajax({
        url: "/BPMS/FormHome/GetData",
        dataType: "json",                   //add this
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",    //add this
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonArray),    //modified
        
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

Or you can use like that for add property:-

```
.....

var d= [{ Id: _id, Value: $(this).val() }];
jsonArray.push(d);

.....

data: JSON.stringify(jsonArray),
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetData([FromBody]IEnumerable <FormFieldsArrayDto> jsonArray)
{
    return Json(new { jsonArray});
}
```

hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @M.baty what you got output after changing?

Comment: Use my two processes of ajax code. @M.baty make sure your ```_id``` and  ```$(this).val()``` contain value. if it does, it will definitely work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just change code of action method and ajax call

Action Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetData(string data)
    {
        List<RootFormFieldsArray> lst=Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootFormFieldsArray>>(data)
        return Json(new { x = "1"});
    }
```

Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/BPMS/FormHome/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: pData},
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: which error you are getting after implementing this ?